# Utility function in graphical game theory

Tags: graph-theory, game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I'm reading a bit about [Graphical Game Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_game_theory), but do not really understand the utility function the model uses.

I'm going to consider a game like matching pennies, but with 3 players: Alice, Bob, and Charlie.

If Alice, Bob, and Charlie all pick heads, (HHH), Alice will lose 1, Bob will gain 1, and Charlie will lose 1 (-1 1 -1).

If Alice and Bob pick heads, and Charlie picks tails (HHT), Alice and Bob will lose 1, and Charlie will gain 1 (-1 -1 1).

Similarly,

$$
\begin{matrix}
HHH: \, (-1, \: 1, \: -1) \\
HHT: \, (-1, \: -1, \: 1) \\
HTH: \, (-1, \: 1, \: -1) \\
HTT: \, (1, \: -1, \: -1) \\
THH: \, (1, \: -1, \: -1) \\
THT: \, (-1, \: 1, \: -1) \\
TTH: \, (-1, \: -1, \: 1) \\
TTT: \, (-1, \: 1, \: -1)
\end{matrix}
$$

How would we get the utility functions from this payoff matrix? Similarly, how would we convert the utility functions back to the payoff matrix?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a case of differing terminology; what I knew as a payoff function was called a utility function.

The problem becomes simple after that,

The payoff of Alice is:

$u(A,B,C) = \begin{cases}1 \; ; \; \{A, B, C\} \in \{HHH, HHT, HTH, THT, TTH, TTT\} \\-1 \; ; \; \{A, B, C\} \in \{HTT, THH\}\end{cases}$

The payoffs for others can be derived similarly.